# how to permanently remove itunes from osx

Tags: macos, itunes

I use osx ( currently 10.11 ) and i don't want iTunes. I've so far been unable to remove it permanently. It just reappears whatever i do. sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app will delete it, but it will just be reinstalled after a while. Right now i have a cron job to check if it is there and remove it, but this seems very dirty.

Does anyone know of a better and more permanent solution?

Comment: I think if you have auto-updates enabled on the Appstore, it will just redownload iTunes anyway.

Comment: Its almost impossible to get rid of Itunes.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of iTunes? What's the real problem?

Comment: iTunes sometimes reset its settings like "don't open when i insert a dvd" etc. And i find that invasive. In any case. Thanks for pointing me to the other answer. I couldn't find it myself for some reason.